# Issue with do while loop C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to solve this question

"Write a do-while statement, the body of which reads an integer from the
console and stores it in an int called hour. Write the loop so that the loop
will exit only when hour has a value between 1 and 23 ."

but my code doesn't work!, what is wrong?

```cs
class numbersLoop
{
    static int Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Write a number:");
       // int hour = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int x = 0;
        do
        {
             int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            if (x >1 && x < 24)
            {
                return 0;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Write a number:");
            int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            
            Console.WriteLine( "The Right number..");
            x++;
        } while (x<10);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: You never assign the read value to x.

Comment: Use two variables, one for the loop counter, and `hour` for the input.

Comment: Also, given the requirement says _”Write the loop so that the loop
will exit **only** when hour has a value between 1 and 23”_, why are you restricting it to 10 tries? Without this you can get rid of `x` altogether

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't assigning the hour variable within your loop, and you're only incrementing x each time through the loop, so the loop will only run twice, then will match the "return 0" case and exit.